# Атрибуты style для тега body.

Tags: html, css

Пожалуйста, кто сможет перечислить все атрибуты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всех свойств я не собираюсь перечислять, вот ссылка, смотрите сами.

http://htmlbook.ru/css